# d3 image is rendering outside the table

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making a table that is reading a JSON file, it needs to output strings on column 1-3 and 7. The rest of the columns (4-6) are displaying 0 or 1 which I was able to implement as strings: "OK" and "NOT OK". However, I would like them to output images instead, but when I call the functions addCheck() and addX(), the images are rendering outside the table.

I am positive instead of a .text() it should be somewhere along the lines of a .append('image') but since I am fairly new at D3 (and JS in general) I have trouble conceptualizing how to append an image to columns 4-6 only, without affecting the rest of the columns that need to output as strings.

Thank you for your help in advance!

```
/* source: http://bl.ocks.org/jfreels/6734025*/

function addCheck() {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "images/success.png";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}

function addX() {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "images/error.png";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}

d3.json(url, function (error,data) {

  function tabulate(data, columns) {
        var table = d3.select('.boxflags-panel').append('table');
        var thead = table.append('thead');
        var tbody = table.append('tbody');

        // append the header row
        thead.append('tr')
          .selectAll('th')
          .data(columns).enter()
          .append('th')
            .text(function (column) { return column; });

        // create a row for each object in the data
        var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('tr');

        // create a cell in each row for each column
        var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
          .data(function (row) {
            return columns.map(function (column) {
              return {column: column, value: row[column]};
            });
          })
          .enter()
          .append('td')
            .text(function (d) {     //PROBABLY SHOULD BE .append() HERE???
                if (d.value === 0) {
                    //return "OK";
                    return addCheck();
                } else if (d.value === 1){
                    //return "NOT OK";
                    return addX();
                }   return d.value;         
                });

      return table;
    }
    // render the table(s)
    tabulate(data, ['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3', 'COL4', 'COL5', 'COL6', 'COL7']);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter the cells selection for the cells you want to add the image. The you can add the `<img>` element just for the filtered cells:

```
// create a cell in each row for each column
var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
.data(function (row) {
       return columns.map(function (column) {
            return {column: column, value: row[column]};
       });
})
.enter()
.append('td')
.text(function (d) { if (d.value !== 1 && d.value !== 0) return d.value;});

// add the imges when the value is 0 or 1
cells.filter(function(d) { return (d.value === 1 || d.value ===0); })
.append('img')
.attr("src", function(d) {
      return d.value===1 ? "images/success.png":"images/error.png";
});
```

Here is a [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/hirebanawo/1/edit?html,js,output)